# How to SQL in many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I want to display how many hobbies does john have. Could you tell me how to write SQL statement?

**PERSON table**

```
ID | NAME
1 | John
```

**HOBBY table**

```
ID | NAME
1 | music
2 | sport
```

**PERSON_HOBBY_COMBINATION table**

```
ID | PERSON_ID | HOBBY_ID
1 | 1 | 1
```

expected result

```
HOBBY_NAME | HOBBY_EXIST
music | YES
sport | NO
```

Comment: Is name in Person table uniques? It looks like it doesn't, so there can be many persons with name John.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
SELECT h.name,  
CASE WHEN ph.id IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS hobby_exist
FROM hobby h 
CROSS JOIN person p 
LEFT JOIN person_hobby_conbination ph ON (ph.p_id = p.id AND ph.h_id = h.id) 
WHERE (p.name = 'John')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select NAME, count(*) AS NoHobbies from Person p
inner join PERSON_HOBBY_COMBINATION phc
on p.ID = phc.PERSON_ID
group by p.ID, p.NAME
```

Note that you should group on both ID and NAME of the person.
You need to group on NAME because you have it in the output, but if you have duplicate names grouping on NAME will sum several persons hobbies together, that is why you need to group on ID too.

**Edit**
When inspection your expected result you don't want how many hobbies John has, but which hobbies. Then you need to write

```
Select p.NAME as PersonName, h.Name as HobbyName, case when phc.ID is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as HasHobby from Person p
inner join Hobby h
on 1 = 1
left outer join dbo.PersonHobbyCombination phc
on p.ID = phc.PersonID and h.ID = phc.HobbyID
```

Comment: I have never thought about group and duplicate names. Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have John's ID and just want a raw count, then this should work.

```
select count(*) from person_hobby_combination where person_id=?
```